# Load Koin module after application starts - Runtime exception

Tags: android, module, koin

We have different modules that we start in Application class. Because we are downloading some config from the server, `user module` is initialised after that. We open splash screen, download the config and after we receive config, we initialise `user module` by using `loadKoinModules`, with `= module(override = true)` for entire module.

After that, we navigate user to MainActivity with its view model, which is using that module. It is happening that we receive `RuntimeException`, to be precise `NoBeanDefFoundException` when view model tries to access that module. This is happening when user is not using the app for a while. I'm trying to learn what happened here.

How is possible that module is not initialised at that moment? Is `loadKoinModule` method asynchronous and because of that is not initialised? Is there any other way to initialise module, based on the use case I described?

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1056